# Add a textView to custom Android view

Tags: android, android-view, textview

I have the following `View`, and I want to add a `TextView` to it.  Does anyone know how that can be done?

```
public class ProgressView extends View {

  TextView text;

  public ProgressView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    text = new TextView(getContext());
    text.setText("Hello");
    // How can I add this to the view now??
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Extend a ViewGroup.

Comment: Nice good call can't believe I didn't think to do that.  If you post this as an answer i'll give you the check

Comment: Actually scratch that, my view doesn't show when i do that

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? And what would your custom `View` or `ViewGroup` do?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a `View` to another `View`, but to a `ViewGroup`. If you want to make it a custom `ViewGroup`, you have to implement `onLayout()`

Answer (score 1):

In order for your custom view to be able to hold other views, it has to derive from `ViewGroup` or a subclass (I highly recommend using a subclass since that gives you a lot for free). Chances are good that you want to be writing `extends LinearLayout` (or `FrameLayout`) instead of `extends View`.

Then you actually have to **add** that `TextView` you've created to your view. Once your view derives from a `ViewGroup`, you can just write

```
addView(text);
```